# Razor View display specific HTML tags

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

To make Razor View display HTML tags to browser we use this

```
 @Html.Raw(Model.Message)
```

I want only b,img allowed to be displayed.  ( Without write a new method to remove all other tags )

Is Razor support it, or method to remove all html tag except b and img  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Razor` doesn't parse `html`. It can encode or decode it, but if you need to remove some tags inside your `Model.Message` - you need to parse it before saving it or displaying.